# Strict Standards: Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm a newbee in joomla. When I change my template to other like http://www.joomla24.com/Joomla_3x_Templates/Joomla_3x_Templates/Oliverio_Lite.html

I'm getting the following error

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in ..\xampp\htdocs\joomla\templates\oliveriolite\index.php on line 91

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in ..\xampp\htdocs\joomla\includes\application.php on line 569
```

Comment: This is what you get when using low quality templates, sorry. Check the line 91 and paste it here, so that we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's quite simple. Your template calls a function named `getMenu()` statically. Meaning the call looks like this: `$app::getMenu()`. But it should look like this: `$app->getMenu()`. The variable name (`$app`) doesn't matter, the colon vs arrow matters.

The correct way to get the menu is:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
```

or even shorter:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
```

Answer (score -1):

Also configure php.ini error_reporting works

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Hiding errors is not a recommended way to solve errors