# how fix theme? joomla 3.1 what change here?

Tags: joomla, themes, joomla3.1

Strict Standards:

> Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/dev/public_html/demo/demo5/templates/as002033free/index.php on
>   line 19

Strict Standards:

> Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/dev/public_html/demo/demo5/includes/application.php on line 593

Strict Standards:

> Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/dev/public_html/demo/demo5/templates/as002033free/index.php on
>   line 41

Strict Standards:

> Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/dev/public_html/demo/demo5/includes/application.php on line 593

Comment: You will need to describe a specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it if you would like some help

Comment: make sure your template compatible with Joomla3.x

Answer (score 2):

I hope error explains itself. `Non-static method should not be called statically.`

It should be like

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
```

## OR

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
```

[More](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/freejoomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=26058)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922391/strict-standards-non-static-method-jsitegetmenu-should-not-be-called-static)