# Sobipro blank screen on search action

Tags: php, sobipro

I'm trying to figure out the problem with my sobipro installation on Joomla 2.5.24 version.
When I try to search something with search form I always get blank screen. 
In my php log i found this errors:

```
[21-Sep-2014 23:22:51 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically in /components/com_sobipro/router.php on line 164
21-Sep-2014 23:22:51 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically in /components/com_sobipro/router.php on line 208
```

Can somebody please help me with search form issue ?

Comment: Is it a duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15956646/248482
Please have a look.

Comment: @TomaszO  no  it's not the same problem , I need to use ->getActive after getting menu, it's returning null so i don't know how to repair it